# Can the size of the training set of a neural network be smaller compared to other models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, sample-size, train

If some of you knows what is the rule thumb *[one in ten rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_in_ten_rule)* this what I want to discuss.

Neural network can, nowadays, go deeper in performances. Did you find, according to your experiences, that you can use less observations (one in five for instance) for the same amount of variables, with neural networks compared to more traditional ML models ?

Besides, if I ask for this, it is in order to avoid "illusions" about the capacities of NN.

Comment: I would argue the opposite, that you need many observations for a neural network. After all, especially a deep network could have 500,000 parameters, perhaps orders of magnitude more.

Comment: @Dave I am not discussing if a deep network is able to deal with 500 000 parameters. I am discussing if a NN with 500 000 parameters can obtain same or better performance with less observations than a classical linear model with 500 000 same parameters, due to the complexity of the model generated by a NN in theory this is the case but I want to know the practicals of people, if they did know the limits of this. Besides I have not the ambition to create such matrix of 500 000 parameters.